# Activiti: Remote process call through Call Activity

Tags: activiti

Is there a way to call a remote sub process via Call Activity? I have a requirement to deploy a bpmn process in a remote server.
I want to run that remote bpmn process as a subprocess within my main bpmn?

Thanks,

Jayant Chaudhuri

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to override the default CallActivityBehavior class by extending the DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory:

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/bpmn/parser/factory/DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory.java

And register your custom ActivityBehaviorFactory in the ProcessEngineConfiguration. In that way you could still be using a callActivity element in your BPMN file.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement this per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see this working is as a REST call to run the remote process from a service task with an asynchronous continuation (i.e. wait for callback from remote service) to move the main process on.

Seems easy enough, but it isn't using Call Activity which only works within the context of your current process engine.